# Как конвентировать колонку с датой в символьном виде в datetime формат?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, datetime, обработка-данных

Есть данные, с датой в символьном виде:

```
0       12/апр/21 3:45 PM
1      12/апр/21 12:41 PM
2       12/апр/21 2:27 PM
3      09/апр/21 11:09 AM
4      09/апр/21 10:47 AM
              ...        
733     22/мая/18 7:49 PM
734     20/июн/18 1:03 PM
735     25/июн/18 3:07 PM
736     29/мар/18 7:37 PM
737     27/мар/18 3:48 PM
```

Как их можно нормально переделать в pandas.datetime формат?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Пример исходных данных:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                   Date
0     12/апр/21 3:45 PM
1    12/апр/21 12:41 PM
2     12/апр/21 2:27 PM
3    09/апр/21 11:09 AM
4    09/апр/21 10:47 AM
733   22/мая/18 7:49 PM
734   20/июн/18 1:03 PM
735   25/июн/18 3:07 PM
736   29/мар/18 7:37 PM
737   27/мар/18 3:48 PM
```

решение:

```
from dateparser import parse  #  pip install dateparser

df["Date_parsed"] = df["Date"].map(parse)
```

результат:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                   Date         Date_parsed
0     12/апр/21 3:45 PM 2021-04-12 15:45:00
1    12/апр/21 12:41 PM 2021-04-12 12:41:00
2     12/апр/21 2:27 PM 2021-04-12 14:27:00
3    09/апр/21 11:09 AM 2021-04-09 11:09:00
4    09/апр/21 10:47 AM 2021-04-09 10:47:00
733   22/мая/18 7:49 PM 2018-05-22 19:49:00
734   20/июн/18 1:03 PM 2018-06-20 13:03:00
735   25/июн/18 3:07 PM 2018-06-25 15:07:00
736   29/мар/18 7:37 PM 2018-03-29 19:37:00
737   27/мар/18 3:48 PM 2018-03-27 15:48:00
```

Comment: Если не секрет, как Вы это загуглили?) Или знали заранее?

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, строка поиска: `"pandas parse non-english date"` ;)